# How to access a fragment that is defined in a different view?

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-fragments, kotlin

I have a fragment that is defined in `activity_main.xml`. I need to reference it inside another class that uses different view. I have the fragment defined in `activity_main.xml` because I need it to be persistent and attached to bottom of main screen. Otherwise I would have it defined inside the view I need to reference it in.

I have tried defining main activity inside my class and using `supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.bottom_sheet_view)` but kept returning error:

```
null cannot be cast to non-null type com.ds.base.fragments.BottomTimeSheet
        at com.ds.base.fragments.SessionTimeFragment.onCreateVie
```

Heres a snippet of how I am trying to instantiate the fragment inside the class:

```
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_session_time,container, false)

        val main = activity as MainActivity
        var frag = main.supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.bottom_sheet_view) as BottomTimeSheet

        if(frag == null){
            frag = BottomTimeSheet()
        }
        bottomTimeSheet = frag
        .
        .
        .
        .
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_navigation_view"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/base_nav_graph"
            />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/bay_number_status"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@color/white_regular"
            android:fontFamily="@font/parkinson_medium"
            android:text="---&#10;Bay #"
            android:textColor="@color/black_regular"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            app:itemBackground="@color/white_regular"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".1"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"
            />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_view"
            android:name="com.ds.base.fragments.BottomNavigationFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_bottom_navigation"
            />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:name="com.ds.base.fragments.BottomTimeSheet"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            tools:layout="@layout/bottom_sheet"/>


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching for the fragment too early in the activity lifecycle. The Fragment's `onCreateView()` is called before the Activity's `onCreate()` is completed. Move the code that tries to get a reference to the other fragment into `onActivityCreated()`.

Answer (score 1):

As Tenfour04 said, you should access the view after your current fragment is created in onActivityCreated or onViewCreated. Or you could also set a tag to your fragment and then try getFragmentByTag.
Hope it helps.